# How to get the whole date time in a single line not separated

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, date, datetime

I need to get the date time in years,month,day,hours,minute,seconds,milliseconds in this format

```
201802281007475001
```

right now i managed to return this:

```
2018418112252159
```

This is my code:

```
var date = new Date();
blockid = JSON.stringify(date.getFullYear()) + JSON.stringify(date.getMonth()+1) + JSON.stringify(date.getDate()) + JSON.stringify(date.getHours()) + JSON.stringify(date.getMinutes()) + JSON.stringify(date.getSeconds()) + JSON.stringify(date.getMilliseconds())
```

I also need to put a zero in front of the `month` and the `day` in case it is minor than `10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to this is to call [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) on the date object and replace the non-required characters with blank:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toISOString().replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

Comment: omg it works, thank you very much, where did you find it?

Comment: Except that the OP seems to want local values and *toISOString* returns UTC values. If UTC is OK, then the regular expression can be simply `/\D/g`.

Comment: @RobG -- thanks for this. It made the code look very simple now.